# CMake's add_custom_command doesnt trigger rebuild of library

Tags: cmake, ninja

Iam using CMake together with ninja to build a library. The library is depending on some code which may be generated before-hand by a custom command. The source for this code is within the source-tree and it must stay there, I have no freedom here.

Here's my CMake code:

```
add_library(some_lib some_source.c)

#some_source.c may be modified by the following custom command
add_custom_command(
    COMMAND codegen.exe -i some_input.xml
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generated"
    OUTPUT  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generated
    DEPENDS some_input.xml
    COMMENT "Generating code ..."
)
add_custom_target(generate_something DEPENDS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generated)
add_dependencies(some_lib generate_something)
```

Now if some_input.xml is changed I want to also rebuild some_lib. However in practice this code doesnt seem to work, the command is executed but after it is executed some_lib is not beeing rebuild, though the timestamps of the output files (some_source.c) of the custom command are newer than the library.

Can someone give me a hint on what am I doing wrong or how I can achieve this? Or is there a problem with CMake and ninja?

Thanks in advance, if you need more information please let me know.

Steve

[edit:]
It seems to be caused by the generator tool, when I use the BYPRODUCTS option of add_custom_command and replace the generator tool invocation by a cmake -E touch command on some_source.c everything works as expected. Can someone give me a hint on how to debug this, why ninja cancels the build after the generator tool has finished?

Thanks, Steve

[edit2]
I found the problem, the problem was that the codegen.exe tool was generating not only one source file but several into an output folder. I need to specify all of these potentially modified sources to as "BYPRODUCTS". Than everything works as expected.

Comment: ".. though the timestamps of the output files (some_source.c) of the custom command are newer than the library." - As your custom command changed `some_source.c`, why don't you specify it as OUTPUT of this command? There is also `BYPRODUCTS` option for [add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html) which is used specifically by Ninja.

Comment: Hi Tsyvarev, thanks for your comment. I dont want CMake to delete the file if a "clean" is executed, though the source is not specified as OUTPUT. Yeah I already tried this BYPRODUCTS option but I couldn't make sense out of it and also Iam not sure if it is associated to my problem. However it didn't had the desired effect, so I decided to ask here for a solution

Comment: Are you sure that your COMMAND modifies `some_source.c` in the source tree, and not creates this file in the binary tree? By default, `add_custom_command` is run in the build directory, not in the source one.

Comment: yeah 1. the build command gets a parameter which specifies the output folder, I omitted this parameter in the code for the sake of simplicity 2. I diffed the timestamps of the library vs the ts of the source file and the source file is younger

Comment: So you need to specify this file - `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/some_source.c` - as BYPRODUCTS for the custom command. Otherwise Ninja won't get an idea that this file can be changed.

Comment: I just tried it, but it has no effect, Iam using CMake version 3.17.2 is this sufficient? Or do I need a recent enough ninja version as well in order for this option to have an effect?

Comment: CMake 3.17.2 should definitely be sufficient for process BYPRODUCTS correctly.

Comment: ok, I also tried to specify the source as an OUTPUT, however it also has no effect, I always need two ninja calls that the library gets compiled: first one so that some_source.c is updated by the custom_command a second time in order that the library gets built. Thats unfortunate.

Comment: when I use the BYPRODUCTS option at least in the status bar of ninja it says [1/7] when the custom command is beeing executed, however it immediatly stops after generation without compiling and linking (i.e. performing steps 2-7.

Comment: it seems to be the generator tool, if I just replace the tool call with a touch command touching some_source.c it works as expected..

Comment: All the source files should be marked as generated by setting the `GENERATED` source file property for them. Also by default the working directory of the command is the current binary directory, i.e. the source generated is probably not the same file that is added as source to the library...

Answer (score 1):

> I dont want CMake to delete the file if a "clean" is executed

`BYPRODUCTS` will still be cleaned.

What can be done is to utilize a dependency tracking file like you've shown (the `"${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generated"`, I used `*.stamp`) and then add the dependency tracking file as an [OBJECT_DEPENDS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/prop_sf/OBJECT_DEPENDS.html) to `some_source.c`

This only works if `some_source.c` is pre-existing.  Initial testing had `some_source.c` get cleaned if I tried to add the [GENERATED](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/prop_sf/GENERATED.html) property.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)

project(in_source_generated)

add_library(some_lib some_source.c)

#some_source.c may be modified by the following custom command
add_custom_command(
    # This is the command that actually generates the in source code file.
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/some_input.c ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/some_source.c
    # This command generates a stamp file which is used as the dependency
    # tracking
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/some_source.stamp"
    OUTPUT  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/some_source.stamp
    DEPENDS some_input.c
    COMMENT "Generating code ..."
)
add_custom_target(generate_something DEPENDS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/some_source.stamp)
add_dependencies(some_lib generate_something)

set_source_files_properties(some_source.c PROPERTIES OBJECT_DEPENDS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/some_source.stamp)

add_executable(main main.c)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE some_lib)
```

A simple `main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int get_value();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("The value is %d.", get_value());
}
```

`some_source.c` and `some_input.c` have the same content. Just toggled the return value in `some_input.c` to test out.

```
int get_value(){
    return 4;
}
```